# get the printers in java from the AS400 server

Tags: java, websphere, ibm-midrange

I can't get the printers on the AS400.

I tried :

```
PrintService[] services = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();
```

No services has been found.

I also searched on JTOpen API. I didn't find anything.

Somebody can help me ?

Comment: What are you running the Java on? Do you have print services setup?

Answer (score 1):

`PrinterJob.lookupPrintService()` defaults to [`DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/print/DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.html) flavor. Could be you have no printers supporting that flavor.

Try running this to check if there are ANY printers found

```
PrintService[] allServices =
           PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
       for (PrintService ps : allServices)
       {
           System.out.println(ps  " supports :");
           DocFlavor[] flavors = ps.getSupportedDocFlavors();
           for (int i = 0; i < flavors.length; i+</i>)
           {
               System.out.println("\t" + flavors[i]);
           }
       }
```

And check what kinds of flavors they support.

Also, are you on iSeries? OS 400? And which Java?

Comment: I'm on a WAS 6.1 which is installed on the AS400. The java version is 1.5

Comment: I tried by your way and it also doesn't work :( no printer are detected

Comment: I'm stretching my knowledge here, AS400 is not my "home turf". Have you verified that you have the appropriate Java Toolbox installed (http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/i/software/toolbox/index.html)? Have you tried accessing the printer using the toolbox api (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/pubs/html/as400/v4r5/ic2924/index.htm?info/java/rzahh/print.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and finally found a solution : according to [Java Print Service IBM Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.2?topic=information-java-print-service) you have to add 2 jars to the classpath for Java to detect printers (and print) on AS400.

These jar files should be located at

```
/QIBM/ProdData/OS400/jt400/lib/jt400Native.jar
/QIBM/ProdData/OS400/Java400/ext/ibmjps.jar
```

In my case the `jt400Native.jar` on the AS400 was way too old for our application (Java 1.1 vs Java 1.8) and caused crash on app startup. I took the latest one from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jt400/jt400 and it worked.

If you run your app from a jar you cannot use `-cp` and `-classpath`, these options are ignored because classpath is set via Manifest file.
In my case (SpringBoot Java 8 Gradle project), I used

```
bootJar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Class-Path': './ibmjps.jar ./jt400.jar'
        )
    }
}
```

to add theses jar to the classpath in Manifest file.